# What is the correct way to build 32-bit libcurl on freebsd?

Tags: libcurl, freebsd, 32-bit

I need to build a 32 bit libcurl.so on freebsd.

If I run ./configure like this:

```
CFLAGS="-m32" CPPFLAGS="-m32" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib32 -m32" ./configure --prefix=/usr/home/debby/libcurl2
```

I get the following errors in config.log:

```
configure:4373: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:4395: gcc -m32 -m32 -L/usr/lib32 -m32 conftest.c  >&5
/usr/local/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/crt1.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/local/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/crti.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/local/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/local/lib/gcc6/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd11.1/6.4.0/crtbegin.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/local/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/local/lib/gcc6/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd11.1/6.4.0/crtend.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/local/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/crtn.o' is incompatible with i386 output
```

Am I even approaching this the right way?  Should I be specifying --build and --host on the ./configure command line instead, and if so what values?

=========

UPDATE

Using the first link suggested by @Wodin I ran configure as follows:

```
export CFLAGS="-m32 -march=i686 -mmmx -msse -msse2 -mfancy-math-387 -DCOMPAT_32BIT"
#export CPPFLAGS="-m32 -march=i686 -mmx -msse -msse2 -DCOMPAT_32BIT"
export LDFLAGS="-m32 -L/usr/lib32 -B/usr/lib32"
./configure --prefix=/usr/home/debby/libcurl
```

make then fails because I don't have the 32 bit runtime libraries

```
[debby@GServerBuild ~/curl-7.60.0]$ make install
Making install in lib
  CCLD     libcurl.la
/usr/local/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/crti.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/local/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/local/lib/gcc6/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd11.1/6.4.0/crtbeginS.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/local/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/local/lib/gcc6/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd11.1/6.4.0/crtendS.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/local/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/lib/crtn.o' is incompatible with i386 output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error code 1
```

Based on the second link provided it seems I need to build those libraries from /usr/src which is empty.

I am trying to get src using `fetch -o /tmp ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/`uname -s`/releases/`uname -m`/`uname -r | cut -d'-' -f1,2`/src.txz` as described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204956/how-do-you-install-the-freebsd10-kernel-sources
and will put an update here on how the rest goes

Comment: This might help: https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/building-in-32-bit-mode-on-amd64.14400/ - if that doesn't work, perhaps try a chroot: https://filipenf.wordpress.com/2011/10/18/cross-compiling-for-x86-in-freebsd-64-bit/

Comment: Thank you @Wodin.  The first link helped.  I ./configure runs now.  Link fails because I don't have the 32 bit crt objects.
I'm going to update my question

Comment: As a matter of interest, why do you need a 32-bit version of libcurl?

Comment: See also: http://web.archive.org/web/20151009061410/http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-stable/2011-March/061902.html

Comment: These instructions work for setting up a 32-bit jail on a 64-bit system. I have just tested it. I didn't bother with the keymap. It complained about using rc.conf for the jail config, but still worked. Apparently you're supposed to use /etc/jail.conf these days, but off hand I don't know how to do that and can't be bothered to look it up right now. https://gundersen.net/32bit-jail-on-64bit-freebsd/

Comment: Try to set `CC=cc` and `CXX=c++`.  The `gcc` binary is from ports and may show weird behaviour.

Comment: The gunderdsen.net article looks like it would have been helpful - in the meantime I had ended up setting up a 32 bit freebsd vmware image and building there instead.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're using /usr/local/bin/ld which is the binutils from ports. Probably doesn't have 32 bit support. Try setting LD.

```
    LD=/usr/bin/ld CFLAGS="-m32" CPPFLAGS="-m32" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib32" ./configure --libdir=/usr/local/lib32
```

Also I checked the file after with readelf.

```
    readelf -h lib/.libs/libcurl.so
```

> ELF Header:
>
> Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>
> Class:                             ELF32
>
> Data:                              2's complement, little endian
>
> Version:                           1 (current)
>
> OS/ABI:                            FreeBSD

The best way would be to make a copy of the Makefile in ports and set.

```
PKGNAMEPREFIX="lib32-"
CFLAGS+="-m32"
CPPFLAGs+="-m32"
LDFLAGS+="-L/usr/lib32"
CONFIGURE_ARGS+="--libdir="${LOCALBASE}/lib32"
```